# I get a column not found exception even if the column exists

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to execute a query against a MySQL database with Java. The code looks like this:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select col1 from tb1 inner join tb2 on tb1.col2 = tb2.col3 where col4='"+foo+"'");
```

The query works perfectly when I use the shell but it doesn't work when I run it with Java because it says that col4 doesn't exist. But col4 exists.

I've just tried something like this;

```
select col1 from dbname.tb1 as a inner join dbname.tb2 as b on a.col2 = b.col3 where b.col4 = 'foo'
```

Comment: What is `col4` actual name?

Comment: Print the exact error here.

Comment: My guess is that the Java is connecting to a different database than the database "when I use the shell". My guess that col4 exists in tb1 or tb2 in one database, but doesn't exist as a column in tb1 or tb2 in the database that Java is connecting to.

Comment: You should also look into using prepared statements within Java.. The variable foo looks to be prone to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the col4 with the table prefix "tb1" or "tb2".

As example: 
select tb1.col1 from tb1 inner join tb2 on tb1.col2 = tb2.col3 where tb1.col4=...

Comment: Yes, best practice is to qualify all column references. But if the reference to col4 was ambiguous, we'd be getting error `1052 Column 'col4' in where clause is ambiguous`, and OP would be getting that error in the MySQL command line client as well.

Comment: I have tried to specify the database name but it doesn' work

Comment: I tried something like this select col1 from dbname.tb1 as a inner join dbname.tb2 as b on a.col2 = b.col3 where b.col4 = 'foo'

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not there. It was I little bit further:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select col1 from tb1 inner join tb2 on tb1.col2 = tb2.col3 where col4='"+foo+"'");
myarray.add(resultSet.getString("col4"));//col4 can't exist here because it has not been selected
```

After executing the query I wanted to access a column that hadn't been selected.